# Play system sounds from one computer through another computer's speakers?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, audio, alert

I have a two Windows PCs at work (one personal and one the companies), one has Outlook on it, and the other one does not.

I use both PCs at the same time with Synergy and SynergyKM.

I'd like to be able to hear my outlook alerts from both of them as I usually wear a pair of headphones and don't hear the alerts.

Is there any "set it and forget it" type solution that might work here?

Answer (score 1):

Spent an outrageous amount of time hunting, but finally found [VACard](http://www.datanab.com/audio/VAcard.htm), which looks like it just *might* be the bees knees.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a high-tech, fancy software based solution, but an easy way is to simply plug the audio output of one computer into the audio input on the one with the speakers attached.

You might have to adjust the various levels, but [something like this](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10218&cs_id=1021802&p_id=5575&seq=1&format=2) should work.

Comment: Doesn't qualify as set it and forget it...(though it isn't too bad)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a forwarding rule? Send a copy of the email to the outlook that alerts you via headphones. Then have a rule that deletes the forwarded email after you are alerted. It's kinda messy, but it's set and forget. More or less.

Comment: So it can send an event reminder that way?

Comment: I'm worried about calendar events (but emails would be good too...)

Comment: Not the events, no. I was thinking email and let rules on the destination handle them. It's not a great solution but I have had to use a similar solution myself. With 2 computers side by side, I think I like Chris' idea better.

Answer (score 0):

**I am assuming that you already connect your laptop and work PC to the same network, but realize that is uncommon in serious work environments. Otherwise, skip this whole thing!**

Google led me to only to [pay-for options](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/49529-streaming-soundcard-output-computer-over-network.html) describing what you sort-of want. [JamCast](http://www.sdstechnologies.com/Wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Virtual-Soundcard&NS=&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) seems to reroute audio but I thought it was free till 5 minutes before ending this post. Sorry. I found it's only a demo with a pay-for conversion. That said: Jamcast or anything else, really, needs to be installed on both PC's, and you have no choice but to convince your boss to install *something* because Windows doesn't just let us squeeze its audio through its network card like Linux supposedly can. You will also need to install it on the headphone PC (easy, it's yours, right?)

Besides the job permissions hurdle, it's unlikely that the transmitter nor receiver program will start automatically without your clicking. You have to ask around to find your transmitter's IP address if you're not allowed to peek. A Startup shortcut that opens the program may be needed on both PC's. That's for the "forget it" part.

As an "instead of" last resort, if your PCs have no firewall blocking and it's legal to connect them, try `mstsc.exe type.your.IPaddress.inhere` (from your Start Menu \ Run). It remote-controls it and redirects all audio when doing so. It is over kill and inevitably does password-lock the transmitter PC. Your screen then will show the real session on the receiver PC, but your boss will wonder why his PC shows only a login screen instead of a working e-mailer. Your options are limited, and I am too tired to try reading the Wiki on what looks like a Pro standard for [audio handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Stream_Input/Output#Utilities_and_plugins)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add Outlook to the other PC. In out look you can add multiple accounts. To me that is the simple fix it and forget it solution. Are the computers connected some type of way. How your computers are connected could be the issue too. I connect my lap top and desk top and do not have that issue. I hope that helps.